# Remove directories from Cloudera Hadoop for a specified number of days

Tags: bash, hadoop

I'm attempting to write a bash script which will allow me to cleanup directories for a specified number of days within Cloudera Hadoop.  I thought about moving files to a temporary directory and then executing a `hdfs dfs -rm`, but I'm not able to use `-mtime` in conjuction with an `hdfs dfs -ls`, `-mv`, or `-rm` within the  Hadoop command syntax. I also thought about a `-moveToLocal`, but that is not an option.  Only `-copyToLocal` or `-get`.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Not Tested)

```
hadoop jar /opt/....../jars/search-mr-*-job.jarorg.apache.solr.hadoop.HdfsFindTool -find /hdfs/ -mtime +365 -rm rvf {} \;
```

1. Where `......` will be the directory in which jars are available(you can
   search the exact directory with locate cmd.
2. Where `+365` for files older than 365 days.
3. Where `/hdfs/` is the directory from where we need to remove files.

For more details check below link -

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/search_hdfsfindtool.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to construct the Hadoop commands in a shell script? that way, you can look for files to clean up after N days and run the job for you.

```
find $dir -type f -name '*.log' -mtime +7 -exec sh cleanup.sh \;
```